# Reversing C++ foo(MyClass &) vs foo(const MyClass &)

Tags: c++, binary, constants, reversing

Suppose I want to **reverse some binary**, will I be able to tell the difference between:

```
int foo(MyClass &) { ... }
```

and

```
int foo(const MyClass &) { ... }
```

Assuming the **code compiled fine**, there would be **no evidence of the const qualifier** whatsoever, right?
I used the following code to test it:

```
class Point { public: int x=6; int y=8; };
int foo(const Point &p){ return p.x+p.y; }
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Point p;
    return foo(p);
}
```

Then compiled with `-g` and `-O0` and dumped:

```
$ gcc -g -O0 main.cpp -o main
$ objdump -D ./main | grep "foo"
000000000000066a <_Z3fooRK5Point>:
 6b6:   e8 af ff ff ff          callq  66a <_Z3fooRK5Point>
```

When I examine the relevant lines it seems the const indeed vanished.

Comment: You probably would be able to, by the function's mangled name. No guarantees of course

Comment: suppose you have both overloads then there must be evidence of the `const` somehow

Comment: The const didn't vanish in `_Z3fooRK5Point` - That K is for const

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica can you provide reference for the mangled naming convention(s)?

Comment: I can't, my experience is anecdotal. But since `c++filt` exists, you can probably start at its source code to get at *some* reference.

Comment: Downvoter please explain, this is a valid question with a simple enough answer suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just pasting @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica's answer for completeness:

```
$ c++filt _Z3fooRK5Point
foo(Point const&)
```